# Loading string and evaluating it memory efficient python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, evaluation

I have a csv which has a column containing list of `floats`, which I evaluate with `json.loads()`.

The problem is that the csv is very big. When I load the whole CSV it takes up to 40 GB of memory.

After evaluating it it's size grows up to 160-170 GB. I tried using a function so it defines a scope and then garbage collector frees the unused memory but it didn't work. I'm using Jupiter Notebook.

I tried to use script, because of the references which Ipython keeps, but that did not solve the problem. I also tried using `pandas.read_csv(..., converters={'float_nums' : json.loads})` - again with no improvement.

Here's the function I use

```
def preprocess(df):
    df.float_nums = df.float_nums.apply(json.loads)
```

How to deal with the problem?

Comment: This is an XY problem. If you have lines of JSONs, you should use `df = pd.read_json(..., lines=True)`.

Comment: I have explained the main problem and an approach which I have tried. Again - I have big CSV with text columns and a column with floats which I have to load as list of floats not string as it is loaded by `read_csv`.

Comment: Then, why would you need json.loads?

Comment: I have also tried `literal_eval()` from `ast` module and the built-in `eval()`, but `json.loads()` turns out to be fastest and giving same results - evaluated list of floats.

Comment: have you tried reading the csv in chunks using `pd.read_csv(..)` ? Look into the `chunksize` argument for read_csv.

Comment: Yes, I tried it.